# Index/match isn't finding certain values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

One of the match values comes from an equation but when typed manually it finds it.

It works for 0.1,0.2,0.25,0.4,0.5 but not 0.15,0.3,0.35.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(($W$7:$Z$15,$W$16:$Z$24,$W$25:$Z$33),MATCH(E11,$AA$7:$AA$33,0),MATCH(E12,$W$6:$Z$6,0),1),0)
```

[image: table of values to match/index]

I think my first match is wrong somehow but I am not sure how.

Comment: Which column is which?

Comment: But this probably has to do with floating precision.  Round the lookup: `MATCH(ROUND(E11,2),$AA$7:$AA$33,0)`

Comment: That worked, could you put that as an answer so I could accept it? I'm not exactly sure why that fixed it either.